# How to use apps in '/opt' in a proper way?

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
From time to time I copy some app (like `xxx`) to the `/opt` folder to be used also by another user-accounts.
Then to start it I use:

```
 sudo /opt/xxx_folder/xxx
```

(of course, links to `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`, etc.) to start it;

Problem: I'm storing the results/projects of the app to my local folder (like `/home/myuser/xxx_data`). And of course the folder and its data `xxx_data` belongs to `root` (not `myuser`). So I have to change the owner every time I want to edit those files using another app not as a `root`.

**Question:** is there a way to install an app `xxx` to `/opt` so, that I don't need to start them as a root?

**OR** maybe you see another way to solve this 'root-user-problem?'

Comment: it's not about '/usr' or '/usr/local', etc. It's about copying app that I don't install from source or via 'apt-get' to root directory AND then having troubles with starting it not as a root AND root ownership of the files saved by this app in my local folder.

Comment: What happens when you run the software without `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you just copy it to `/opt`, just `chmod 755` on the directory and the executable to allow it to be run by everyone. As for the output, a good way to do this is make the folder owned by a particular group, and add any users that should be able to modify `xxx_data` to the group, like this (run as root):

```
groupadd xxx_data
chown root:xxx_data /path/to/folder
chmod 770 xxx_data /path/to/folder
usermod -aG xxx_data <username> #Repeat for each user
```

You need to run `chmod 755` on your home directory as well, or else move `xxx_data` elsewhere.

You may have to logout and back in to update the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Programs you install via apt-get (or aptitude) will almost always end up appropriately in /usr. BUT programs you compile from source and make install will more often end up in /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/lib, etc, and you may have problems with that since the user-installed path in Debian/Ubuntu is /usr and not /usr/local.

When compiling from source, add this switch to configure: ./configure --prefix=/opt. This way when you make install the files will end up in the right directory